# Django Model forms: how change html of a field

Tags: django, django-forms

### My goal first:

Here's the output of Django:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label>Statut:</label>
    <label for="id_statut" class="sr-only">Statut:</label>
    <ul id="id_statut">
        <li><label for="id_statut_0"><input class="form-control" id="id_statut_0" name="statut" title="Statut:" type="radio" value="1"> Marié(e)</label></li>
        <li><label for="id_statut_1"><input class="form-control" id="id_statut_1" name="statut" title="Statut:" type="radio" value="0" checked="checked"> Célibataire</label></li>
        <li><label for="id_statut_2"><input class="form-control" id="id_statut_2" name="statut" title="Statut:" type="radio" value="2"> Divorcé(e)</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's how I need the formatting:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Statut:</label>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="statut" id="id_statut_0" value="option1" checked="checked">Marié(e)
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="statut" id="id_statut_1" value="option2">Célibataire
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="statut" id="id_statut_2" value="option3">Divorcé(e)
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

### And my configuration:

Here's my model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Personne(BaseModel):
    STATUT_CELIBATAIRE = u'0'
    STATUT_MARIE = u'1'
    STATUT_DIVORCE = u'2'
    TAB_STATUT = {STATUT_CELIBATAIRE: _(u'Single'),
                  STATUT_MARIE: _(u'Married'),
                  STATUT_DIVORCE: _(u'Divorced'), }
    statut = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                              choices=[(a, b) for a, b in
                                       list(TAB_STATUT.items())],
                              default=STATUT_CELIBATAIRE)
```

Here's my form:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Personne
        fields = ['statut']

    statut = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        label=_(u'Statut:'),
        choices=[(k, Personne.TAB_STATUT[k])
                 for k in Personne.TAB_STATUT],
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
            'title': _(u'Statut:'),
            'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Note that I've tried to add '`class`' attribute.

Here's my template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group {% if field.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
        <label>{{ field.label }}</label>
        <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}"
               class="sr-only">{{ field.label }}
        </label>
        {{ field }}
    </div>
    {% if field.errors %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">{{ error }}</span>
            {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {{ field.help_text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main options are:

1. mark up the whole thing in a template (you can get all the needed information form the `field` object) or
2. subclass the `RadioSelect` and make yourself a new widget.

Here the second choice is shorter.

[`RadioSelect`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L779) is defined like this:

```
class RadioSelect(RendererMixin, Select):
    renderer = RadioFieldRenderer
    _empty_value = ''
```

And all the magic is in the [`ChoiceFieldRenderer`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L679) (parent class of the [`RadioFieldRenderer`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L734)):

```
@html_safe
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ChoiceFieldRenderer(object):
    """
    An object used by RadioSelect to enable customization of radio widgets.
    """

    choice_input_class = None
    outer_html = '<ul{id_attr}>{content}</ul>'
    inner_html = '<li>{choice_value}{sub_widgets}</li>'

    ...
```

So all you need is to change `outer_html` and `inner_html` code for a new renderer.

You can do it this way:

```
# coding: utf-8
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import RadioFieldRenderer
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .models import Personne


class MyRadioFieldRenderer(RadioFieldRenderer):
    outer_html = '{content}'
    inner_html = '<div class="radio">{choice_value}{sub_widgets}</div>'


class MyRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):
    renderer = MyRadioFieldRenderer


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Personne
        fields = ['statut']

    statut = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        label=_(u'Statut:'),
        choices=[(k, Personne.TAB_STATUT[k])
                 for k in Personne.TAB_STATUT],
        widget=MyRadioSelect(attrs={
            'title': _(u'Statut:'),
            'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Output I've got with your template:

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <label>Statut:</label>
    <div class="radio">
        <label for="id_statut_0"><input class="form-control"
            id="id_statut_0" name="statut" title="Statut:" type="radio" value="1" />
            Married</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label for="id_statut_1"><input class="form-control"
            id="id_statut_1" name="statut" title="Statut:" type="radio" value="0" />
            Single</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label for="id_statut_2"><input class="form-control"
            id="id_statut_2" name="statut" title="Statut:" type="radio" value="2" />
            Divorced</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that's perfect, I was answering the solution, which is **exactly** your answer. I cant believe how easy it is to understand Django's source code. Would it have been Symfony I'm sure I would never have been able to find that!